# summation of polynomial products

Tags: summation

I need help in understanding how the summation of the product of two polynomials is written.

$(a_{0} +a_{1}x +a_{2}x^{2})(b_{0} +b_{1}x + b_{2}x^{2}) =\\ (a_{0}b_{0})x^{0} + (a_{1}b_{0} + b_{1}a_{0})x + (a_{2}b_{0} +a_{1}b_{1} + a_{0}b_{2})x^{2} + (a_{1}b_{2} + a_{2}b_{1})x^{3} + (a_{2}b_{2})x^{4}$

I can not figure out how to write this as a general summation.
Thanks

Comment: What is your question? Because this goes by definition. Take for example, $(4+3x-x^2)(2-5x+3x^2)$ and see what happens, respecting the definition.

Comment: I can't tell the edit sequence, but both AaronMaroja & Claude ignore the summation aspect of the question.  Writing it in sum notation seems to be the point.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Distribute the product $$(a_{0} +a_{1}x +a_{2}x^{2})(b_{0} +b_{1}x + b_{2}x^{2}) =$$ $$(a_{0} +a_{1}x +a_{2}x^{2}) b_0 +(a_{0} +a_{1}x +a_{2}x^{2}) b_{1}x+(a_{0} +a_{1}x +a_{2}x^{2})  b_{2}x^{2}$$ Expand now what is inside the brackets and group together the terms showing the same power of $x$. Remember that $x^0=1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_m$, coefficients be
$$sum   a_j*b_k$$ where j+k = m

So the resulting polynomial is

> Sum m=0 to 4 of $C_m$ * $x^m$

Please fix my MathJax/ LaTeX, simply figuring out the answer and how to notate it took significant effort.  I invite you or encourage you to check this by writing out a few terms of the sum.

Comment: That is helpful. Thanks. How do you write the summation